# Handling notifications at scale

Tags: scalability, notifications

How do applications like twitter handle notifications at scale.

For example @BarackObama has 131.3 million followers. When he tweets, how is that notification sent to all 131.3 million followers.

I supposed you could load all 131.3 million followers one page at a time and update some state point to that new tweet, but it seems highly inefficient and I would imagine it would take some long that you would have to be mindful of people following / unfollowing during this process.

Are there any better ways?

Comment: The Twitter databases are surely a highly distributed system, using techniques like sharding, and the notification services will surely work parallelized.

Comment: See also: [The Infrastructure Behind Twitter: Scale](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/infrastructure/2017/the-infrastructure-behind-twitter-scale)